# Scroll bar not appearing during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbars

I had search on scroll bar not appearing topic.
i believed my problem is the same as others but the solution but it seems none of them help.
I had a few button which i create in design stage within a panel, when some button are out of the area of the panel, the IDE does show the scrollbar which i set Autoscroll to True.
However during runtime, i cannot see any scroll bar nor can i scroll into those control that is out of the area of the panel
I tried Anchor the buttons all around and it does not help. Setting AutoScrollMinSize to a large value also does not help.

Am i missing other ways?

**Edit
Attached is a picture i snapshot during design and runtime
[image: Panel and Buttons]

Comment: Try setting 'Autoscroll' to 'True' for the form, may be panel has the scroll bars but the panel width/height is beyond the size of Form.

Comment: Hi Mukul, i did already set the autoscroll to true for the panel. And the panel itself is part of the form and is smaller than the form.

Comment: Are you sure that the panel is actually the size that you think it is?  Is it possible that the panel is actually larger than you think but is hidden behind other items in the view?

Comment: Hi LordWilmore,The panel is a container for all the buttons. I am sure the panel is not big because i show its borderline. One of the button in the panel is half 'Cut off' meaning it is out of the panel viewable area.

Comment: is the height of the panel the same while you're designing that at runtime? have you set AutoScrollMinSize for this panel?

Comment: This would be my point during development when I whip out [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). Btw: a [mcve] would certainly help here.

Comment: Hi mcNets, i tried setting AutoscrollminSize to a very large value like 20000 but still it doesn't show. The height of the panel is not change during design or runtime stage

Answer (score 2):

try Setting Panel **AutoScrollMinSize**

```
    panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, 10); // 10 or Minimum Height you require
```

If the above also didnt work check the tab order and make the panel to be on the top most parent.

I feel you are making some changes in runtime. Your Design-time Screenshot and runtime screen seems to have background difference, try setting **AutoScrollMinSize** again after setting background

Comment: Hi Prashanth. This works although the background image is 'slicing' when scroll. The button container panel was not change in anyway during runtime. I just put the color of the buttons in the panel to transparent. But i must say that the panel container panel is actually in another panel but i doubt this is the problem. in your opinion, what is actually causing the problem? So in future we can take note.

Comment: Another funny sight i see. if i include Prashanth code, it works. But that is provided in design stage AutoScrollMinSize is 0,0. If in design stage AutoScrollMinSize is 0,10 and also include Prashanth code, the scroll bar disappear again....!